# Styling a Textblock autogenerated in a ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, controltemplate

As I saw, a lot of people ran into this exact problem but I can't understand why my case is not working and it is starting to drive me crazy.

Context: I have a `DataGrid` which is to be colored according to the values of each cell. Hence, I have a dynamic style resolving the actual template to be used for each cell. Backgrounds now work accordingly.

New problem: when I have a dark background, I want the font color to be white and the font weight to be bold so the text is correctly readable. And... I can't style it correctly.

I read some Stackoverflow posts about that:

[This one fits my problem but doesn't provide me any working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739530/how-to-change-textblock-default-properties-for-a-contentpresenter-in-a-template)
[This one is also clear and detail but... duh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063264/contentpresenter-within-controltemplate-cannot-change-attached-dependency-propert)
[This is almost the same problem as me but... Solution does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970285/wpf-4-contentpresenter-textwrapping-style-is-not-applied-to-implicitedly-generate)

Here is what I tried so far:

```
<!-- Green template-->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Green" TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
        <Grid Background="Green">
            <ContentPresenter
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BoldCellStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" />
                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Does not work. Background is green, but text stays in black & not bold.

BTW, the BoldCellStyle is as easy as it can be:

```
<Style x:Key="BoldCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

Okay. Second try (which is a real stupid one but well...)

```
<!-- Green template  -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Green" TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
        <Grid Background="Green">
            <ContentPresenter
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="BoldCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </Style>

                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
            </ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Doesn't work either.

Then, I tried to play with the `ContentPresenter`'s properties:

```
<!-- Green template -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Green" TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
    <Grid Background="Green">
        <ContentPresenter TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" TextElement.Foreground="White" TextBlock.Foreground="White"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And... As you can expect, this does not even work.

Intrigued, I used Snoop to browse all the components of my interface.
In the first two cases, Snoop actually shows me that each cell is a `Grid` with a `ContentPresenter` containing a `TextBlock` and the actual `Style` but... The `TextBlock`'s properties do not apply and `FontWeight` is still normal.

Last case, even more shocking, I can see that snoop shows me that we actually have a `ContentPresenter` with the right properties (ie `TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"`), but the autogenerated `TextBlock` under is - still - not styled.

I can't get what am I missing here. I tried as you can see almost all I could possibly do here, and the `TextBlock`s keep being non-formatted.

Any idea here? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataGridColumns` that derive from `DataGridBoundColumn` (all except `DataGridTemplateColumn`) has a property `ElementStyle` that is applied to the `TextBlock` when it is created. For e.g. `DataGridTextColumn` It looks like this

```
static DataGridTextColumn()
{
    ElementStyleProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGridTextColumn),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DefaultElementStyle));
    // ...
}
```

It overrides the metadata for `ElementStyle` and provides a new default value, `DefaultElementStyle`, which basically just sets the default margin for the `TextBlock`.

```
public static Style DefaultElementStyle
{
    get
    {
        if (_defaultElementStyle == null)
        {
            Style style = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
            // Use the same margin used on the TextBox to provide space for the caret
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.MarginProperty, new Thickness(2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0)));
            style.Seal();
            _defaultElementStyle = style;
        }
        return _defaultElementStyle;
    }
}
```

This style is set in code everytime a new `DataGridCell` is created with `element.Style = style;` and this is overriding the Style you are trying to set, even if you try to set it implicitly.

As far as I know, you'll have to repeat this for your columns

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" ElementStyle="{StaticResource BoldCellStyle}" .../>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" ElementStyle="{StaticResource BoldCellStyle}" .../>
```

Comment: Wow. Am I absolutely forced to do that? The main purpose of my work here is to style each cell separately (some of them are bold, some others are normal)

Comment: @Damascus: Yes, as far as I know. You can still use the same Style though, you just have to apply it to every column.

Comment: I juste tried it and it "works" (yeah, it sets all my cells to bold), I'll try to play with Triggers to make it then :/

Comment: @Damascus: Aha, I thought that was what you were already doing :) Missunderstood.. But yes, hopefully you'll be able to make it with triggers

Comment: So, Triggers are - partly - done. If youre interested in what happens next (cause yeah, there is still a problem), feel free to read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107044/styling-datagridcell-correctly/7107215#7107215  :)