# Styling DataGridCell correctly

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, controltemplate

This is a question following my previous problem, [you can find it right there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092145/styling-a-textblock-autogenerated-in-a-contentpresenter)

So. Now I defined a `DataGrid` with a specific `ElementStyle` for each column (which just defines the `TextBlock`s inside in bold & white -- will come over this problem later)

So now I have two questions

**First question (solved)**

When I happen to set a background to my cell, it overrides the default style, and the background stays the same when the cell is highlighted.

One example of a style:

```
<!-- Green template for market-related -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Green" TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
    <Grid Background="Green">
        <ContentPresenter
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I'd naturally say that this is "normal" because I set the `Grid`'s background to Green. I therefore tried it this way:

```
<!-- Light green template for sophis-related -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LightGreen" TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
    <Grid Background="LightGreen">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type tk:DataGridCell}}, 
                                            Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="#FF3774FF" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This won't work either. As you can see I put a DebugConverter so I can check that the trigger is actually called, which is the case, but... Background does not change (and Snoop confirms this...)

Third try:

```
<!-- Light green template for sophis-related -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LightGreen" TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
        </Style>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And... No background will be displayed (stays transparent)

So I think I am working in the wrong way here and I was wondering what should I do to JUST define the "not selected" template.
I would say that I may need to define a style BasedOn the "classic" style but, how would I do that? I tried to add TemplateBindings with no success

** EDIT: Solution**

As H B suggested in his answer, problem was coming from DependencyProperty Precedence, here's the solution:

```
<!-- Light green template for sophis-related -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LightGreen" TargetType="{x:Type tk:DataGridCell}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type tk:DataGridCell}}, 
                                            Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="#FF316AC5" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type tk:DataGridCell}}, 
                                            Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Second question**

Now, let's speak `Triggers`.

Basically, what I want to do is to define specific `Triggers` to my `ElementStyle` so the font color is white if the cell's background is Red or Green (the only aim of this is to have a better readability as Red and Green are kinda dark, black font on dark background results in a nice fail :p )

**Edit** Seems like I'm not clear enough: the following style is the style applied to each item of the datagrid, through the property `DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle`. Here is the code handling that:

```
    void VolatilityDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn column = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
        column.ElementStyle = s_boldCellStyle;
        // Other stuff here...
    }
```

Here is what I do:

```
<!-- Cell style for colored matrix-->
<Style x:Key="BoldCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type tk:DataGridCell}}}" 
                     Value="Red">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type tk:DataGridCell}}, 
                                Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}"
                     Value="Green">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
</Style>
```

And... It doesn't work. Strangely, what goes through converter is ONLY transparent background colors. I am definitely missing something here!
BTW, I also tried with classic triggers, no success either, I use `DataTriggers` here so I can debug the binding values!

Now I've been stuck for more than three days on this and I'm starting to freak out... Hopefully the Stackoverflow community will save me :)

Thanks!

**Edit**

Okay, update.
I understood why my `Trigger` does not work. The Background actually set is on the `Grid` and NOT on the `DataGridCell`. It is therefore normal that I don't get any color set there.

However, I ran some tests and found out that when the binding is set, the `TextBlock` does not have any parent yet (`Parent` = null). Binding to a `RelativeSource` of type `Grid` will bind me to... The whole `DataGrid` items presenter.
I'm not sure what to do now, since it seems like that from the actual `TextBlock` style I can't reach the parent `Grid` and therefore cannot resolve what color should I display according to the background.
Also, I can't change the Font color in my `ControlTemplate` because the `DataGrid` wants a `Style` for each column, which overrides the template's style by default [(see my previous question and its answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092145/styling-a-textblock-autogenerated-in-a-contentpresenter)
So... Stuck again I am!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

This:

```
<Grid Background="LightGreen">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <!-- Trigger Stuff -->
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Needs to be:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            <!-- Trigger Stuff -->
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

---

Not sure about your second question as of now, possibly a related problem, i would suggest setting `TextElement.Foreground` instead of `Foreground` for starters. Getting `Transparent` as value is not very helpful, what control template do you use for the `DataGridCell`? If it is custom, is the `Background` hooked up properly via a `TemplateBinding`?

This works as long as the `Background` property is used, so if you have a `ControlTemplate` which sets things internally you need to externalize that. A normal `DataGrid` example:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content}" Value="Apple">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content}" Value="Tomato">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" Value="Red">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" Value="Green">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
</Style>
```

So if the `CellStyle` sets the `ControlTemplate` the properties need to be hooked up via TemplateBinding. e.g.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content}" Value="Apple">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Content}" Value="Tomato">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Do not do the triggering inside the template or it will get messy.

Comment: Thank you for the useful link! First problem solved thanks to you :) About the second, it's a style defined for `TextBlock`s, so should I really work with `TextElement.Foreground` ? I am editing the question because I found out what possibly is the cause -- which may pose a new problem even trickier :/

Comment: @Damascus: The fact that at first there is no parent should not be that problematic. I still do not get **where** you use that style and how it interacts with the other components though, your question needs more context about that.

Comment: Woops, sorry, just updated the question, the style is used as a `DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle`, check this out :)

Comment: Got it! You're totally right, externalizing was the solution. Thank you very much!