# How to style ContentPresenter in ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, styles

I'm currently styling `ComboBox` to look like one in Visual Studio (along with color theme). I've done most of the styling, but stopped at the `ContentPresenter` displaying the currently chosen object.

The piece of XAML looks like the following:

```
<ContentPresenter Margin="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Name="ContentSite"
                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                  Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}" />
```

The problem is, that the default `SelectionBoxItemTemplate` seems to ignore ComboBox's Foreground value:

```
<ComboBox Margin="4" SelectedIndex="0" Foreground="Red">
    <ComboBoxItem>First</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Second</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Third</ComboBoxItem>                
</ComboBox>
```

[image]

The first one is non-editable, `SelectionBoxItemTemplate` kicks in and forces set the color of the text to black (even though `Foreground` is set manually to red and in style to another non-black color).

How can I pass the current foreground color to the `ContentPresenter`? If I can't, where can I find working replacement for the `SelectionBoxItemTemplate`? (working, in terms, that it'll work correctly for all item types in the `ComboBox`)

Comment: It happened to be that another user asked the same question today. Instead of copy pasting everything to here I will suggest you to read my answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116418/set-style-for-all-elements-inside-contentpresenter/20117653#20117653 Here is a link to a tutorial of how to solve those style inheritance issues: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/08/27/implicit-styles-templates-controls-and-frameworkelements.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it does ignore the `Foreground` colour. If you add a (normal) `ComboBox` control like the following to your XAML...:

```
<ComboBox Foreground="Red">
    <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Four</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

... you will see that setting the `Foreground` *does* change the selected item text. I think that perhaps your problem lies in *your* `ControlTemplate`. Now I can't be 100% sure, but I would have thought that your `ContentPresenter` should look like this instead:

```
<ContentPresenter Margin="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="ContentSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding 
    SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" />
```