# WPF button style not being applied to child element

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a button style like this

```
<Style x:Key="NormalButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="ContentSite">
                    <Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" Style="{DynamicResource NormalButtonTextStyle}"/>
...
```

Where the style for the ContentPresenter is

```
<Style x:Key="NormalButtonTextStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultFontStyle}">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource NormalTextOnDarkBackgroundBrush}" />
...
```

So then I defined my button like this

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource NormalButtonStyle}">
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="Cancel"/>
...
```

But the TextBlock does not end up with the `NormalButtonTextStyle` style. I inspected the elements during runtime and the content presenter definitely has the right text foreground, but then the child TextBlock ends up inheriting from something entirely different and gets a foreground of `ControlTextBrush`.

Am I misunderstanding how styles are applied to child elements? How am I supposed to define the button so that the style is applied correctly?

Comment: Have you tried including the `ContentPresenter` style inside `ControlTemplate.Resources`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `<Setter />` to the `Button` `style`:

```
<Style x:Key="NormalButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource NormalTextOnDarkBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="ContentSite">
                    <Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Why doesn't the same setter work in the content presenter, though? I don't get why the difference is important.

Comment: The style of a ContentPresenter is not applied to a Button element.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116418/set-style-for-all-elements-inside-contentpresenter). "The proper style would be inside ContentPresenter just in this case the ContentPresenter is not part of logical tree."

```
<Style x:Key="textBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>


<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter>
                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource textBlockStyle}"/>
                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: To clarify: as the linked answer explains, the above snippet *does not work in this case* - see `<TextBox Text="It doesn't work this way!"/>`. So this is not a solution. Follow the link to see explanation. And to see that a work-around is to do what Max did: put the text directly in the button, instead of in a child textblock. Of course this doesn't help in the general case, where one really wants to affect a child element.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are probably the right way to fix this, but unfortunately the styles are used in a huge application so I prefer a solution that only affects the button. The question linked to by Parisa helped; I need to set the Content of the button directly so that the text's parent is the ContentPresenter:

```
<Button Content="Cancel" Style="{StaticResource NormalButtonStyle}"/>
```