# ContentPresenter Resources not applied when added as LogicalChild

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, contentpresenter

My custom control is derived from `ContentControl` and has an additional dependency property 'AdditionalContent' of type `FrameworkElement`.
This property is bound to a `ContentPresenter` in style that has custom style resources:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentSource="AdditionalContent">
  <ContentPresenter.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      ... some setters ...
    </Style>
  </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

As I learned from other questions here, I have to add this object as logical child of my control by calling `AddLogicalChild(AdditionalContent)` and overriding `LogicalChildren` property.

Now, if I use my control like this

```
<MyControl>
  <MyControl.AdditionalContent>
    <Button .../>
  </MyControl.AdditionalContent>
</MyControl>
```

The style for `Button` is not applied. And that's the correct behaviour, because of style inheritance (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20117653/2224147)). So I have to apply the style in the place where I define the `AdditionalContent`. So far so good.

But **strange** behaviour: when I leave out adding the object as logical child, the styles *are* applied.
Why does this happen? And is there a proper way to provide styles for all contents inside `AdditionalContent` similar to define `Toolbar` styles?

Comment: I don't know where you got the info that the style won't be applied, but it is wrong.
The style was declared right before the button instance on the visual tree,
And so it will be applied. Nothing strange here.
If you wanted  a different behavior, then the Button instance should declare a different style for itself.

Comment: @Mishka please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20116418/2224147). The `Button` will not get the style applied, what is the correct behaviour. But I wonder why leaving out the `AddLogicalChildren ` changes this.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell since you have left out much of the button definition, but try setting the style of the button to a dynamic resource with the button type as the resource key.

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource {x:Type Button}}"/>
```

When adding a default style with no resource key like you have done, the implicit key is the data type.

By setting the style to a dynamic resource you are indicating that the resource could change during runtime, which is the case when you are inserting it into the tree at runtime like you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for this approach, but doesn't work. Button definition doesn't contain more than Command and Text.