# How change the cutom label's forecolor ,when there is a global style for type TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, label

Now ,I define a style for Type TextBlock as a global resource,in other way the `TextBlock` now has a default style in my application. I want to add a bottom border for label. But I don't know how to change the textblock in label's forecolor as I want (eg.I　want to make its forecolor as blue ). now the label's subchild `TextBlock` use the default style.

```
<Style x:TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFF0" /> 
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type Label}"
   TargetType="Label">
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
      Value="Left" />
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
      Value="Top" />
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
    <Border>
      <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
               Value="false">
        <Setter Property="Foreground">
          <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the forecolor of the label dynamically ?

Comment: @OsmanEsen First I want make it as a satic resource.Maybe I will consider it as dynamically changes.

Answer (score 0):

Solution one:
The style can add a bottom border for Label and override the global `TextBlock` Style.

```
 <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="TodoPlaceHolder">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Corbel" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#F0F0F0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">

                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                               Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                               FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                               FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                             Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Solution two:
using the style replace the `TextBlock` in Label's Template.

```
<ContentPresenter TextBlock.FontFamily="Tahoma"
              TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="4,0,0,0"
              ContentSource="Header"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
```

[How do I Change the FontFamily on a ContentPresenter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401600/how-do-i-change-the-fontfamily-on-a-contentpresenter?rq=1)