# WPF Change Background color of a Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, background-color

In my WPF app I just want to change the background color of the Combo box. I don't mean the dropdown, I want is just whatever item is selected a background is set. 
Like setting the background of a button - when the control is displayed on screen it should have LightYellow background. That's it. 
 I searched a lot on net, but everywhere could find solutions for drop down background colors. I tried applying SolidColorBrush and Style.Triggers to the TextBlock of Combobox, but no success as wanted. By adding SolidColorBrush lines, I got my dropdown background set, but that's not what I am looking for. My code is :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MtrCm}" SelectedValue="{Binding WellboreDiameter_Unit, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,26,249,0" x:Name="cboWellDiameter" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"   Background="LightYellow"  >
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Can anyone help me set he background of the desired component that am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this

```
 <Window.Resources>  //Put this resourse n Window.Resources or UserControl.Resources
   <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
      <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
         <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDC3939" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE80E0E" Offset="1.0"/>
         </GradientStopCollection>
      </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
   </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFFBE618" />

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="2"
  Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
  BorderThickness="1" />
            <Border 
  Grid.Column="0"
  CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" 
  Margin="1" 
  Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" 
  BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
            <Path 
  x:Name="Arrow"
  Grid.Column="1"     
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
    </ControlTemplate>


<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox">
  <Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
      <Grid>
       <ToggleButton 
         Name="ToggleButton" 
         Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
         Grid.Column="2" 
         Focusable="false"
         IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
         ClickMode="Press">
      </ToggleButton>
      <ContentPresenter
        Name="ContentSite"
        IsHitTestVisible="False" 
        Margin="3,3,23,3"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
       <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
         Style="{x:Null}" 
         Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         VerticalAlignment="Center" 
         Margin="3,3,23,3"
         Focusable="True" 
         Background="Transparent"
         Visibility="Hidden"
         IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
      <Popup 
        Name="Popup"
        Placement="Bottom"
        IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
        AllowsTransparency="True" 
        Focusable="False"
        PopupAnimation="Slide">
        <Grid 
          Name="DropDown"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
          MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
           <Border 
            x:Name="DropDownBorder"
            Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
            BorderThickness="1"/>
           <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
           </ScrollViewer>
          </Grid>
         </Popup>
        </Grid>
       </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
   </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
 </Window.Resources>
 <Grid>
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    </ComboBox>

 </Grid>
```

Here is the complete style that you can change : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Can I share this same style with my few other UserControls ? I want to use the same style for combos in my 5 UserControls (I have many). Can I access it in those without writing the same in all 5 controls ??? I doubt so, but would like to confirm.

Comment: The selected item doesn't appear on top. Tried many variations to set the forecolor but no affect. Why the selected item is not visible on top ? I mean even after selection the combobox appears blank - instead the selected items should appear on top. What to set for the same ?

Comment: @Tvd The selected item does not appear because the ContentPresenter is missing some attributes:

  `Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}"
  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
  ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"`

Comment: This is so disappointing about WPF... So much code just to set background of a ComboBox.

Comment: Thanks @Optimax The answer should deffo be updated with your comments!

Comment: This is a good example of why WPF is such a mess (even a failure?). They should just start from scratch again.

Comment: Is it possible to make it show the ComboBox.Text property if no item is selected in XAML?

Comment: Is not that WPF is difficult. Just that whoever wrote the default template for the controls, hard-coded the colors onto the template, instead of inheriting provided system colors. IMHO, that's just bad coding. 2022. I'm surprised no one has bothered to update the controls with inheritable colors. Or perhaps they're just afraid that it might 'look' broken in case someone (like me) decided to mess with system colors in the resource dictionaries.

Answer (score 26):

While I like the accepted answer the problem I have with it is the text box presenter was completely missed and thus you can select and stylize things but they will never be presented to the end user.  I think the easiest way to achieve a combo-box that shows data and then when chosen displays it would be this:

```
<Window http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test" x:Class="MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="200">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxTest2" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Grid>
              <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
                <ToggleButton.Template>
                  <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <Border x:Name="Border"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CornerRadius="5" Background="Beige" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
                      <Border Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"  Margin="1"  Background="AliceBlue"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
                      <Path x:Name="Arrow" Grid.Column="1"  Fill="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                      <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                      </Trigger>
                      <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                      </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  </ControlTemplate>
                </ToggleButton.Template>
              </ToggleButton>
              <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False"  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3"  />
              <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
              <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True"  Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                <Grid  Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                  <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="Blue" />
                  <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                  </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
              </Popup>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel Margin="10">
    <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTest2}">
      <ComboBoxItem>Item1</ComboBoxItem>
      <ComboBoxItem>Item2</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The key parts of the presentation needed to be done is the template 'ToggleButton.Template' for the initial display.  I chose to ignore making more brushes and links to more templates and just do it all inline so others could play with it as needed.  I also chose what I thought were easily Identifiable colors to just jump to for reference it should look like below when it works:

[image: ComboBoxPicture]

Comment: Very nice! But now how to set the text color of the text in the ContentPresenter? EDIT: Ah, it's via the `TextBlock.Foreground` property on the `<ContentPresenter>`, answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249671/changing-the-foreground-colour-of-a-contentpresenter-in-a-listbox

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS 2012 or VS 2013 in the Document Outline window while viewing your xaml get the control template of a combobox. 
Find the style `x:Key="ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton"`  and update the `RenderMouseOver = "False"` and `RenderPressed="False"` on the Themes:ButtonChrome and also comment out the trigger that affects IsEnabled.

[image: My Combo box when I dont click on it]
[image: My Combobox when I click on it]

Below is the one on I edited on my box to illustrate what I mean.

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="False" RenderPressed="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="False"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <!--<Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#AFAFAF"/>-->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: For this I need to add Aero or any so assembly, otherwise this also fulfills my need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to put a TextBlock onto the combobox, but the TextBlock should be smaller than the ComboBox so that the drop down button is not hidden. In the TextBlock the desired background color can easily be set. When the selected item in the ComboBox changes, the text block has to be updated.

XAML code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TestComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" 
          Margin="35, 5, 0, 0" SelectionChanged="TestComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="TestTextBlock" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Margin="36, 6, 0, 0" Padding="4,1" Width="126" Height="20">
  <TextBlock.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow"/>
  </TextBlock.Background>
</TextBlock>
```

C# code:

```
private void TestComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)TestComboBox.SelectedItem;
  if (cbi != null)
  {
    TestTextBlock.Text = cbi.Content.ToString();
  }
  else TestTextBlock.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows 8 or 10 this is proper WPF way without redesign the Combobox and 100% customizable.

Just copy paste and test! :)

[Click here to see how look the ComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Av1.png)

```
  <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Combo_Custom"
    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2" x:Class="Test_Combo_Custom.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">


<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Background" Color="Yellow"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFFF0C00"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFB0F0F"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border" Color="#FFABADB3"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background" Color="#FF88E00A"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Background" Color="#FF000000"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background" Color="#FF00FFC5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#FF101AEC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background" Color="#FFC91355"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF606060"/>


    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton2" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                    <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton2}"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                    <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton2}"/>
            <Border x:Name="border" Background="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                    <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyleCustom" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="317.429,194.428,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyleCustom}">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <!-- color of ComboBoxItem -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}" Color="#FF17FF00" />
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox> 

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: In what way is this "not redesigning the ComboBox"

Answer (score -4):

Just add the following to your `ComboBox` style :)

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}"
```

Example:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    //Other setters, triggers, etc...
</Style>
```

Believe me, it's probably the shortest way to do it... I don't see why we have to completely re-define the `ComboBox` template.

Comment: It doesn't do anything

Comment: I get this error Message: The resource "{x:Type ComboBox}" could not be resolved.