# ComboBox of colored TextBlock WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to create `DataGrid` each cell is `ComboBox`, each `ComboBox` lists a colors list, and the selected value by default is read from database.

My problem is that I couldn't color the background of each item in the `ComboBox` according to the colors list

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ComboBoxColumnTemplate">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource = "{Binding ColorsList}" >
               <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="" Background="{Binding ???}" />
                  </DataTemplate>
               </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
         </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

How can I accomplish this?

UPDATE >>>

I tried the suggested solution by `Sheridan`

, it works for me, but when I select an item the background of ComboBox doesn't take the background of the selected item.
 I need this because I use the ComboBox for color selection.

Thank you.

Comment: ColorsList is a list with what object?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what exactly is inside your `ColorsList`... if it is a collection of `SolidColorBrush`es, then you could simply do this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Colours}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="Put some text in here" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.Background" Value="{Binding}" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

However, if it is a collection of type `Color`, then that won't work because the `TextBlock.Background` is of type `Brush`.

---

UPDATE >>>

I've updated the code example to use the `ItemContainerStyle` instead because that will color the *whole* `Background` of the `ComboBoxItem`, rather than just the `TextBlock`.

Comment: Thank you it works, but if I select one of the colors it doesn't appear as selected item in the ComboBox

Comment: Strangely, that is not as simple as you might imagine. Take a look at the answer to the [WPF Change Background color of a Combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695145/wpf-change-background-color-of-a-combobox) question. P.S. Take a look at my code update.

Comment: I know it's not simple but I'm trying to understand and figure it out. I just don't understand why when I select some item it doesn't get the background of this item and put it as background for the ComboBox

Comment: The default `ControlTemplate` of the `ComboBox` is what is colouring its `Background`, so to enable you to do it, you'd have to define your own `ControlTemplate`... that's why.

Comment: I'm sorry for my inconvenience, but in some other place I'm using ComboBox but not in a grid, and it works normally. My Code is:   <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxStatus_Input" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
ComboBoxStatus_Input.ItemsSource = UIStatus.StatusColors.ToList().ConvertAll(color => new TextBlock { Text = "", Background = new SolidColorBrush(color.Value) });

Comment: Did you just un-accept this answer to ask another question? Poor show.