# Changing background color for a ComboBox, it's not changing color at all

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I going crazy that I just can't change the color of the ComboBox. Have tried to use the background property right on the ComboBox but nothing happens.

Have also tried to use a Style block and set the background color, but that does also not work.

**Code**

```
<ComboBox Padding="7" Height="34" Background="#ffffff">
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="black" />
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
            <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">1 - Room</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>2 - Rooms</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>3 - Rooms</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>4 - Rooms</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>5+ - Rooms</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

Even though that I have set the background color to white, It still only the standard grey color.

Here you can see how it looks:

[image]

Hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695145/wpf-change-background-color-of-a-combobox). Looks like you'll have to implement your own ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

here are several thing which in my opinion can help you:

1. Remove the Background definition from the ComboBox declaration(Background="#ffffff").
2. Move the combo items declaration to the combo holding Grid because of the fact that ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container.
3. Implement the data template selector to support data templates of combo (one for selected item, second for the items to select).

**Here is the XAML code**

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type system:String}" x:Key="MyRoomsArray">
            <system:String>1 - Room</system:String>
            <system:String>2 - Rooms</system:String>
            <system:String>3 - Rooms</system:String>
            <system:String>4 - Rooms</system:String>
            <system:String>5+ - Rooms</system:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ComboBox Padding="7" Height="34" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyRoomsArray}">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemToSelect">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Background="Red" 
                            BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=BorderBrush, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                            BorderThickness ="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=BorderThickness, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding }" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedItem">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=Background, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"  
                            BorderThickness ="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=BorderThickness, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding }" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <wpfComboBAckground:ComboDataTemplateSelector x:Key="ComboDataTemplateSelector" Selected="{StaticResource SelectedItem}" ItemToSelect="{StaticResource ItemToSelect}"/>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource ComboDataTemplateSelector}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

**Here is the data template selector**

```
public class ComboDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var selected = false;
        // container is the ContentPresenter
        FrameworkElement fe = container as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe == null) return ItemToSelect;
        var cbo = fe.TemplatedParent as ComboBox;

        if (cbo != null)
            selected = true;

        return selected ? Selected : ItemToSelect;
    }

    public DataTemplate Selected { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate ItemToSelect { get; set; }
}
```

**How it looks like:**
[image: here]

Regards.