# WPF - change combobox style depending on itemtemplate

Tags: wpf, combobox

I need to create a combo which will show a simple text(enum) value when its drop down is closed. but when user clicks drop down, it should show a complex data template with more information in combo box item.

I have created two data templates to show different information when drop down is closed or opened.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DropDownOpenedTemplate">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <!-- Complex template -->
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel >
                                    <Image Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding ImageUri}" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0" />
                                    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,0,0,5"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,0,0,0"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DropDownClosedTemplate" >
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <!-- default template -->
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then I created a template selector which will override SelectTemplate method

```
public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        ContentPresenter presenter = (ContentPresenter)container;

        FrameworkElement elemnt = container as FrameworkElement;

        while (container != null)
        {
            container = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(container);
            if (container is ComboBoxItem)
                return (DataTemplate)presenter.FindResource("DropDownOpenedTemplate"); ;
        }
        return (DataTemplate)presenter.FindResource("DropDownClosedTemplate");

    }
```

This functionality is working correctly. but now I need to format style depending on template used. To simplify, I need background color of combo box to be blue when dropdownclosedtemplate is selected, yellow when dropdownopenedtemplate is selected and selected item should have background as red.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="spComboBox" Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Width="200"
                  Margin="30"
              Background="Blue"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ModeList}" 
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMode, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector}">
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    </ComboBox>
```

I can see only yellow color but not able to change style for dropdownclosedtemplate and selecteditem style when dropdownopenedtemplate is selected.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use relativesource= but use elementname=spComboBox you can get the binding working easily. But I don't think you need it at all, if I understood your three states correctly (if not, please specific, maybe with an image showing all states).  I added a textbox to show that kind of binding. it works for the datatrigger, too. But I think if you want to test it, it should compare against True and not false as in your example.

Here's my solution:

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   >
<StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="spComboBox" Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Width="200"
                  Margin="30"
                  Background="Blue"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" >
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi1">Item1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi2">Item2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi3">Item3</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                                <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1" Padding="3" Background="Yellow">
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                </Border>

                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
           </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        </ComboBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=spComboBox, Path=IsDropDownOpen}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    </Window>
```

It shows Blue, when nothing is selected. when you open the dropdown, all items are yellow, if you select one, that has background =red (although it is not easy to immediatelly see, because the cursor is directly set to it, hiding the color, but you'll see it is red, once you move the cursor)

For the background-color in closed state, [this answer should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22696386/2582968)

Comment: Thanks Jan for replying. When template selector is present, I cannot change background color of combobox to be blue by just changing background property. You are right about using IsSelected property instead of IsDropDownOpen property (I made a mistake in my code) but even after changing property to IsSelected, the code does not change color of selected combobox item.

Comment: @Dhan Can you check if the isselected works with my code bits? Source: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1211/wpf-items-control-advanced-topic

Comment: @Dhan I think the last link in my answer should solve the last problem, although it is far from an easy solution