How do I show that a combobox has multiple entries?
I'm working on a C# project, based on XAML.
I have a combobox, which mostly will contain just one entry, but in several cases, it might contain more.
I would like to warn the user about the possibility of multiple entries. I know I need a converter for that, but I'm just wandering if such a thing already exists.
Currently, my combobox looks as follows:
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb_Locations"
          Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="2"               
          ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredLocations}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          Background="{converters:RatioConverter}">
</ComboBox>

(The mentioned converter is just bogus.)
Does anybody know about a simple converter for such a thing?
The proposal of Denis is great, but it changes the foreground colour instead of the background, but the name seems not to be Background, but what should it be?
Current situation: the green arrow shows what is changed, the red rectangle shows (a part) of what I want to change (the entire background, in fact):

Edit: ±progress
In the meantime I've been working further, and amongst others getting some help from ChatGPT, I now have the following code in my XAML file:
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb_Locations"
           Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
           Margin="2"               
            ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredLocations}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightCoral"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Items.Count}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGreen" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=Items.Count}" Value="1" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Violet" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>

This has the following effect:
When there is only one item, something happens, which is great!
The thing, which happens, can be seen here:

As you see, the "green" trigger has been executed, turning the foreground colour into green.
Where there are more items, something happens, which is great too!
The thing, which happens, can be seen here:

As you see, the "LightCoral" trigger has been executed, turning the foreground colour into lighcoral.
Also, the background colour of the items changes into yellow.
However, the thing which does not happen (and that's what I'm after), is the changing of the background colour of the very first item: that ALWAYS stays the same.
How can I achieve the very first item to have its background modified?
Another edit: I've done a test:
Just as a test, I've added a very simple other ComboBox to my XAML:
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb_test" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

However, this gives the following result in the Live Visual Tree:

This gives me the impression that there is somewhere another object, causing that wrong behaviour, but where?

Just my 2 ct.: Don't pre-select a value and force your users to make an active selection for a required field.

@Filburt: what do you mean?

I mean you shouldn't rely on mere visual cues if it is important to obtain a conscious choice from your users.

You can use triggers for this. In the example below the text is always red if there is more than one item, and black if there is exactly one item. Of cause just the color change is not very intuitive, but it gives you a starting point:
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />                    
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Items.Count}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

You could also set the isEnabled property to false, this way the user knows there is only one option available.
Note from the question author: in order to completely understand this answer, it is necessary to read the comments and to check the other StackOverflow post, mentioned there.

It's more than an hour that I'm trying to decypher this with the "help" of ChatGPT, giving no results, but your proposal works marvellously. Just one question: I would not like the foreground colour to change (that's the colour of the letters), but the background. Unfortunately, it seems not to be "Background" because this changes nothing. Do you know the name of the "Background" property of a combobox?

In the meantime, there's some evolution. Can you check the edits of my question? Thanks in advance.

you will find one of the dark spots of the WPF world. the combobox is a pretty messed up control... Setting the background of it is just stupidly complicated... you will have to combine this question with what you have learned today:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695145/wpf-change-background-color-of-a-combobox
Glad i could help you a bit by showing you the world of triggers in WPF styles

honestly the easiest implementation in my opinion is preselecting if only one option is available and setting IsEnabled=false  and if there are multible valid options just not preselect anything, forcing the user to investigate the available options by opening the combobox

I had a look at the accepted answer of the other question you referred. If I'm understanding this correctly, it's not about modifying the properties of a combobox, but about creating another collection of controls (a textbox, a popup, some other stuff) in order to simulate a combobox. Am I right?

every control in wpf uses a tempate and a style. You can change the template via the style. The template dictates how a control looks. Most controls are implemented properly by mircosoft so changing any of their properties like the background do what you expect. On a combobox however the microsoft implementation is not ideal causing the properties not to behave as you would expect. to change this we need to change the template, thats what the other question is describing

Thanks a lot for your help, I now have a far better understanding of the hell I arrived in :-)

Welcome to suffering! Jokes a side: Once you get used to it its the bes GUI framework i have ever used! You can do anything with it.

Instead of modifying the comboboxes style and template you could just show and hide a textbox like this:
                        <StackPanel>                            
                            <ComboBox x:Name="combo">
                                <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>
                            <TextBlock Text="there is more than one option available">
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />                    
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=combo, Path=Items.Count}" Value="1">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>

