# WPF C# Set "ContentPresenter.Foreground" by code

Tags: c#, wpf, foreground, contentpresenter

I could only find xaml specifiy solutions to this problem using `TextElement.Foreground="..."`.
But I'd like to set the Foreground of a ContentPresenter in C#.
Can you tell me how that works?
Thank you very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249671/changing-the-foreground-colour-of-a-contentpresenter-in-a-listbox

Comment: @malkam Thanks, but this is an xaml solution as well...

Comment: Have you chacked attahed properties out? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attached properties is what you are looking for. You can check [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In general, you'll want to do something like myContentPresenter.SetValue(ForegroundProperty, myForeground)